# Zariski closure of the subset of a line.

Tags: polynomials, zariski-topology

Let $K$ be any field, and $F=V(f)$ a Zariski closed subset of $K^n$ such that $F\cap L$ is infinite for a given line $L$.

> Why does $L\subset F$ hold ?

If $n=2$ for instance, we may assume that the line $L$ is given by $x=0$ for instance, so $f(0,y)$ has infinitely many roots hence it is zero, so $f(x,y)$ vanishes on $L$.

But what for bigger $n$ ? What I understood is that $L\cap F$ is infinite, hence cannot be discrete, by compactness. So it is kind of big... but why as big as $L$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F\cap L$ is Zariski closed, and the closed subsets of the line are either finite or the line.

Comment: Well. Why are the closed subsets of the line finite or the line ?

Comment: Because they are zero of a polynomial

Comment: How do you define a polynomial on the line ? Why is a zariski closed subet of a line (for the induced Zariski topology) a zero set of a **one variable** polynomial ?

Comment: ok I got it, because a line is the intersection of n-1 hyerplane so one can express n-1 coordinate in terms of one...